# Modal forms not displaying

Tags: python, modal-dialog, flask-wtforms

i am working on a project, and i created two modal forms on the landing page. both forms are for registration and login.
only one form seems to be coming up and the other cannot come up and thereby making it impossible for the forms to submit.

how do i achieve this challenge, that both forms can be displayed and can submit to the database respectively.

also i am a rookie i just started a few weeks ago

i have tried and all i keep getting are errors or only one form displays

```
@app.route('/main', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    form = Signup_Form()
    forms = Login_Form()
        if request.method =="GET":
        return render_template('/main.html', form=form, forms=forms) 
    if request.method == "POST":
        return render_template('main.html', form=form, forms=forms)
    else:
         return redirect('home.html')
```

i expect to see both forms display when clicked and also submit to the database when the submit button is clicked

Comment: So you want to display both registration and login form in the same page? did you tried to handle this in html page?

Comment: @pratibha, yes i did. I had written the codes on html first before taking them to python. and they worked perfectly.